# Editing PHPBB theme without going through the admin panel

Tags: css, notepad++, phpbb, phpbb3

I am currently working on a custom theme for a phpBB forum.

I installed phpBB on a local web server with Wamp and all my files are there and the website is working correctly.

The problem is that I cannot edit the style with Notepad++ and then just saving, the changes are not showing up when I look in my browser even if I press <kbd>F12</kbd> and look at the CSS code. The code never changes.

The only way I found is to go edit the style through the admin panel (`Styles -> Theme -> Edit`).

Am I doing it wrong with Notepad++? Is there something special I have to do so I don't have to edit it from the admin panel?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Themes in phpBB have to be imported and applied whenever you want to use them. Assuming you are updating and saving the files that are actually being used, then you'll need to go into phpBB Administrator Control Panel.

Once there, navigate to the **Styles** tab, and click **Refresh** for the Template or Theme of the style you have been editing. This will clear the styles from the cache of the board and should allow your new styles to be applied.

Comment: Thanks! You're right! And with your answer I've made some research to see if it is possible to do it automatically and yes it's possible. It is possible to do that by going through the load settings in the admin panel and setting Recompile Stale Style Components to yes.

Comment: Your comment - answer helped me. Please post it as a answer to your own question, so it will be more easy to find.